# I need to set the height of a div according to the size of the window when the page is loaded and when the page is resized

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, function

I need a function that sets the height of a div according to the size of the window when the page is loaded and when the page is resized.

Instead I have a function that only adds to the length of the div, only when the window is resized.

I am not good at javascript myself, and this is the very last thing I need before my webpage is completed, so any help would be greatly appreciated!

This is the page, and the div in question is the light gray infobox (containing text and a button) on the left: http://goodshitdesign.no/

This is the code for the function I currently have:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(window).on("resize", function() {

        var bodyheight = $(document).height();

        $(".infobox").height(bodyheight);
    });
});
</script>
```

Comment: Put the code in a function. Call the function when the page is loaded, and also use it as the handler for the `resize` event.

Comment: If the CSS messes it up, the CSS is the problem, not the JS. Don't use JS for styling when CSS is better, faster and designed to do what you want.

Comment: `resize` only gets called when the page is resized, which only happens after `ready`. This is not the proper way to do what you want, `CSS` is the proper way. *you are doing it wrong* is a valid answer regardless of what you want.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No need of using Javascript to set the dimensions relative to the viewport.

Use [viewport percentage height](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/length#Viewport-percentage_lengths)

> 1/100th of the height of the viewport.

```
.infobox {
    height: 100vh;
}
```

---

**If** you still want to use JS(*I don't know why when using CSS will be better approach*),

1. `resize` event binding is not required to be wrapped in `ready`
2. To get window height use `$(window).height()`
3. Use `trigger` to force execute event handler on page load

Code:

```
$(window).on("resize", function () {
    $(".infobox").height($(window).height());
    //                   ^^^^^^^^^
}).trigger('resize');
// ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

Answer (score 4):

Have you considered using `vh` and `vw` CSS units instead of JavaScript?

```
.infobox { width: 100vh; height: 100vh; }
```

- Support: http://caniuse.com/#feat=viewport-units
- Details: http://snook.ca/archives/html_and_css/vm-vh-units
- Docs: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/length#Viewport-percentage_lengths

Answer (score 0):

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".infobox").height($(window).height());
    $(window).on("resize", function() {
        $(".infobox").height($(window).height());
    });
});
</script>
```

'resize' do not run when page is loaded. Therefore on page ready you just create a event handler for resizes that will occur in the future.

Answer (score 0):

your script works as it is. in order to resize your div onload, simply call the .resize method without any parameters.

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(window).on("resize", function() {
        var bodyheight = $(document).height();
        $(".infobox").height(bodyheight);
    });
    $(window).resize(); // THIS EMULATES THE RESIZE EVENT ONDOCUMENTREADY
});
</script>
```